# FatalThrowableError in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I get an error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::update()

here is code

```
$user = Auth::user();

$user->name = 'name';
$user->update();

return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: Is somebody logged in? `Auth::user()` should return an instance of `User` which it clearly does not in this case thus nobody is (properly) logged in. Did you set the proper middleware on your routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need update user from **User** model and then update **Auth** onject

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
$user->name = 'name';
$user->save();
```

**Update Auth:**

```
Auth::setUser($user);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if user is authenticated, then you can update name:

```
if (auth()->check()) {
    auth()->user()->update(['name' => 'name']);
} else {
    dd('User is not authenticated');
}
```